# Shapeless HList appender

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to write a function that would append an `HList`, I found that `Updater` is the closest to what I want:

```
  def appender[L <: HList, V, Out <: HList](hl: L, k: Witness, v: V)(implicit updater: Updater.Aux[L, FieldType[k.T, V], Out]) : Out = {
    updater(hl, field[k.T](v))
  }
```

I have this function that updates and appends an HList, but I'd like to disable the update and only allow the function to append, so that:

```
val hl = 'field1 ->> 1 :: HNil
appender(hl, 'field2, 2) //should compile
appender(hl, 'field1, 2) //should fail
```

Currently both compile. Anyway I can express this constraint with Shapeless? I thought maybe possible to ask evidence that the `Out` type is one element longer than the in type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shapeless.ops.record.LacksKey`:

```
  def appender[L <: HList, V, Out <: HList](hl: L, k: Witness, v: V)(implicit
                                                                     updater: Updater.Aux[L, FieldType[k.T, V], Out],
                                                                     lk: LacksKey[L, k.T]) : Out = {
    updater(hl, field[k.T](v))
  }
```

Comment: @jamborta `L LacksKey K` checks that the list `L` does not contain any element with the key `K` (checks to make sure there is no element of the type `FieldType[K, _]` in `L`). This restricts the `Updater` to only append to the list, because it can only modify the list if the key already exists

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here's an answer that uses your length-checking idea. The `LacksKey` way is better, though. Also, `Updater` creates duplicate keys if you reuse a key but use a different type (because, after all, the type is really part of the key), which means that this `append` does the same.

```
def append[
  Value,
  In  <: HList,
  Out <: HList,
  InSize   <: Nat,
  OutSize  <: Nat,
  AddedNum <: Nat
](in: In, key: Witness, value: Value)(implicit
  update: Updater.Aux[In, FieldType[key.T, Value], Out],
  inSize:  Length.Aux[In,  InSize],
  outSize: Length.Aux[Out, OutSize],
  addedNum: ops.nat.Diff.Aux[OutSize, InSize, AddedNum], // ops.{hlist, nat}.Diff conflict
  sizeRestriction: AddedNum =:= _1 // Bonus: error messages are fairly readable: "Cannot prove that AddedNum = Succ[_0]" (followed by a horrifyingly long "not enough arguments" error).
): Out = update(in, field[key.T](value))
```

Note that all the type-level values in your computation need to be type parameters, because you can't have parameters with types that mention other parameters in the same parameter list. You need to be rather careful to never ask the compiler to do more than it can handle each step of the way.

Comment: Thank you. It's an interesting approach.